# How does delegation work in array OrderBy method in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, lambda, delegates

I'm learning delegation with array data structure in C#. Please take a look at my code. I tried to expand lambda expression and delegation in array OrderBy() method in order to fully understand how it works. But Visual Studio gives syntax error even though the running result is correct. I'd appreciate it if someone can help me correct "delegation 3" part. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test2 {
    class Program {

        delegate int Del(int i);

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            int[] MyArray = new int[5] { 3, 2, 6, 10, -3 };

            // print original array
            foreach (var i in MyArray) {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            //Console.ReadKey();

            // sort array by using either Linq or OrderBy
            // Linq works
            //int[] mynewarray = (from i in MyArray orderby i ascending select i).ToArray();

            // delegation 1 works
            //int[] mynewarray = MyArray.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
            // delegation 2 works
            //int[] mynewarray = MyArray.OrderBy(delegate (int i) { return i; }).ToArray();
            // delegation 3 has syntax error
            Del del = MyInt;
            int[] mynewarray = MyArray.OrderBy(del(int i)).ToArray();

            // print sorted array
            foreach (var i in mynewarray) {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();


        }
        public static int MyInt(int i) {
            return i;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `del(int i)` is not c# syntax. You either should invoke delegate `OrderBy(i => del(i))` or pass it as parameter `OrderBy(del)`

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I tried del(i) too. But it still gives syntax error.

Comment: Another option would be  `OrderBy(MyInt)`

Comment: Thanks juharr. Your advice works. But is that possible to use delegate here, without anonymous class or Lambda? Just like go back to the time of C#1.0 or 2.0. So it helps me understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an input identifier (`i` in this case) and use the "goes to" (`=>`) operator.

option 1:

```
int[] orderedArray = MyArray.OrderBy(i => del(i)).ToArray();
```

option 2:

```
int[] orderedArray = MyArray.OrderBy((int i) => del(i)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Aominè. Your advice works too. Is that possible to use delegate only, without anonymous class and Lambda? So it will help me understand better. Thanks again.

Comment: what do you mean _Is that possible to use delegate only_ ?. A delegate is simply a type that specifies a method's signature and references the methods that permit that criteria.

Comment: @ZhongjieFan do you mean creating a delegate using an anonymous method? i.e `Del d = delegate(int k) { /* ... */ };`?

Comment: Your option 1&2 make sense to me. Thanks. But I need to take time to understand that. I learned an example today with which I want to take the logic. Let me see if I can post below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I learned today. Below is a very traditional way to use delegate (c#1.0). It's just a way to help me understand delegate. I actually wanted to use below way of delegate in the code I posted in my question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DelegateDemo_2 {
    class Program {

        delegate bool IsTeenAge(Student stud);

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            // reference: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-lambda-expression

            IsTeenAge isteenage = new IsTeenAge(CheckAge);
            Student stud1 = new Student() { Age = 17 };
            Console.WriteLine(isteenage(stud1));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool CheckAge(Student s) {
            return s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 18;
        }
    }
}
```